# Need to list the rows contained in a count(*) Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for your help.

I'm having troubles with an SQL query in access.

I have 
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VaRB.png)

I need the following output ( show and list the Store Number and PaidMoney ONLY where  Paid money is the same amount 2 or more times only)
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLsUu.png)

I already have 2 queries which kind of solve the problem, but each of the queries I have only solve 50% of the answer I need, the first lists all the results not only the duplicates , and the second query tells me how many duplicates there are but doesnt list and show the duplicates to me.

**First Query**

```
SELECT StoreNumber, PaidMoney 
FROM Stores
```

**Second query**

```
SELECT StoreNumber, PaidMoney, COUNT(*)
FROM Stores
GROUP BY StoreNumber, PaidMoney 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**Thank you all for your time and help!**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a little easier to read the question if you can post the data in the text as opposed to in a linked screenshot. It's not clear to me what additional information you want to see since the second query shows the same StoreNumber and PaidValue values as the first  (in addition to the calculated count).

Comment: Thank you for your warm welcome!, Sorry about the images,sadly when I put the table as a text it lost the formatting so there was no visual way of seeing it, will try to keep editing until I make it visible with text

the second query shows StoreNumber,PaidAmount and a third column with the number of times the PaidAmount is repeated.

I need to see as a list StoreNumber and PaidAmount with the repeated values, NOT  only once with a number saying how many times it was repeated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The repeated values will just be the StoreNumber and PaidAmount repeated, just like the first query. If you can show what your desired output is - that may help.

Comment: The desired output is in the second image, link to it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLsUu.png

Comment: Oh - so you really just want to filter rows out that only appear one time?

Comment: Yes!, and if the amount is repeated from 2 to x times list the x times it was repeated.

Comment: I just edited the answer. You don't really need the `count(*)` in the select list of query 2. I just left it as it originally was, but - it just occurred to me. It will need an alias to be joined with another query so I added one. Or - you could omit it from the select list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the 2 queries together and only "select" the columns from the first query. The second query will just filter out the rows from the first query that only appear once. Rows from the first query that appear more than once should appear as many times as they appear in the first query.

```
 SELECT q1.StoreNumber, q1.PaidMoney
 FROM (SELECT StoreNumber, PaidMoney 
       FROM Stores) q1
      INNER JOIN (SELECT StoreNumber, PaidMoney, COUNT(*) ct2
                  FROM Stores
                  GROUP BY StoreNumber, PaidMoney 
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) q2 
              ON q1.StoreNumber = q2.StoreNumber 
             AND q1.PaidMoney = q2.PaidMoney
```